# What's the meaning of "moar repoz"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase appears in this article:
https://blog.jupyter.org/the-big-split-9d7b88a031a7
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a joking misspelling of 'more repos'. A repo (or repository) is a source of available software that users of the Python programming language can install for specific purposes. The 'moar' misspelling is an example of 'lolspeak', which is mostly associated with the [Lolcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolcat) internet [meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme).

Comment: Thanks, that's really hard for a non-native guy to understand. :)